# QXmlStreamReader, codec utf-8 needed

Tags: qt, qxmlstreamreader

I have a UTF8 XML file. I am parsing it to retrieve the attributes, but the attributes retrieved are not in UTF-8, instead I am getting `??????` for any of the UTF-8 values.
The file has text in some other language, that is in UTF-8.

```
QFile* file = new QFile("d://in.xml");

if (!file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
         return;
}
QXmlStreamReader xml(file);
QList< QMap<QString,QString> > head;

while(!xml.atEnd() &&
        !xml.hasError()) {
    QXmlStreamReader::TokenType token = xml.readNext();

    if(token == QXmlStreamReader::StartDocument) {
       xml.documentEncoding();
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: Does your xml file starts with line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` ?

Answer (score 2):

I have not used the XML streams myself, but if this is a similar problem as mine, you may need to set the `QTextCodec` to UTF-8 as follow:

```
#include <QTextCodec>
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
```

Do that around the time you initialize your `QApplication` or `QCoreApplication`.